# How to associate a newly allocated C structure to a lua created object and automatically free it when the lua object is closed/GC-ed

Tags: c, lua

Say I have a lua object created with io.open/io.popen. is there a way to bind a C structure to it by calling some c defined function from lua that takes the (io.open/io.popen)-ed object as an argument and binds a newly allocated struct to it?
the purpose of wanting to do this is so I can hopefully keep that newly allocated structure around until the lua object gets closed or garbage collected and have that free the C structure automatically at that point.
I've been reading on metamethods but I'm not sure I want to overwrite the default object behavior (maybe just add an extra function?) or if that's even the right approach to achieve the above.
Any help/hint on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*Say I have a lua object created with io.open/io.popen*" That's more of a C object, probably some form of userdata.

Comment: so then I'll have to somehow bind lightuserdata (c struct) to userdata (lua io object)? and somehow trigger a c function that will free it when the userdata is closed/gc-ed?

Comment: Lightuserdata does not support metamethods. You need full userdata.  But it can just be a boxed pointer. See several examples in my libraries at https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/